# Deploy a Angular Application on windows server using jenkins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, jenkins

Im trying to deploy a Angular 7 ASP.Net MVC application to windows server using jenkins with out any continuous integration.

Im using the following steps

1. Pull the repo from Git. 
   In Execute windows batch command im using  following commands
2. npm install
3. ng build.
4. using ms deploy to create the package
5. moving the published website to destination folder

but after npm install the jenkins is not running the ng build command and moving to next step and the build is completed with out any errors.

Kindly help if im missing any thing here.

Updated here as im not able to isert screen shots in the comment--

[Steps in build environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhL6F.png)

- [Result when i try to run the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d31Nw.png)

Comment: So is it running ng build or not? Please add some punctuation to your question.

Comment: can you share your shell script code for `npm install` and `ng build`

Comment: try installing angular-cli as a global package in your window machine.

Comment: Hi please see above where i have updated the screen shots in the question as im not able to add them in here. Thanks